# is it possible to have group by sort in any order other than ascending?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that joins a couple of tables and produces a lot of rows, in a situation where I only wish to see one row per user.  I have solved the "only one user" problem by using group by user.id, however, I'm noticing that now for each user I get the values from the joined table that represent the first entry (rather than the last).

so in other words

```
user:
id | phone

item:
id | user_id | timestamp
```

my intention is to join these tables and select the latest item (based on timestamp, or item.id desc) but to only get one item per user (rather than see all the items that each user has).  `group by user.id` solves the problem of giving me just one item per user, but they always turn up with the first item that has the lowest item.id, whereas I want the most recent one.

Is there a better way to achieve this... I was initially noodling with `distinct` but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

TIA

[EDIT]
In response to Jocelin's question below:
`select user.id, item.timestamp from item join user on user.id = item.user_id order by user.id`

Comment: something along the lines of: `select user.id, item.timestamp from item join user on user.id = item.user_id order by user.id`  I can't paste the actual query cause it's really convoluted. I'm stripping it down to its essentials here.

Comment: Use 'Group By user.id' and 'Order By item.id desc' both ?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: click "edit" (below the question) to add relevant information to your question.

Comment: I tried order by item.id in conjunction with group by but it's still producing just the lowest numbered item... perhaps I'm overlooking something... *should that work?

Comment: I think you're overlooking the keyword `desc`

Comment: @Erty, no adding desc only changes the order in which the rows that are found appear.  It doesn't change the order in which the joined (item) rows are located, so, the same (lowest id) values show up in the field, even as the resulting joined table is presented in an alternate order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql has a "cheat" for getting the first row only of each group:

```
select *
from (select
        u.id as user_id,
        u.name,
        i.id as item_id,
        i.timestamp
      from user u
      join item i on i.user_id = u.id
      order by timestamp desc -- "desc" = order descending
    ) x
group by user_id
```

The "cheat" is that mysql allows you *not* aggregate the non-group by columns (unlike every other database I know). Instead of giving an SQL syntax error, it returns the *first* record only of each group. Not SQL standard, but very handy.

The beauty of this is that you don't need any correlated subqueries, which are dreadfully slow.

The inner query is used to order the records in timestamp latest-first order, so the first record encountered for each user is the "most recent".

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Use an `ORDER BY` with `DESC` clause:</strike>

```
select 
  user.id, item.timestamp 
from 
  item 
join 
  user on user.id = item.user_id 
group by
  user.id
order by 
  user.id DESC
```

I'm suspecting (from your comments below) that your issue isn't really what you describe. Try something like this instead (untested, because I don't use MySQL - it works in SQL Server and SQLite):

```
select
  user.id, i.ts
from 
  (select id, max(timestamp) as ts from items group by id) i
join
  user u on u.id = i.id
```

Comment: that puts them in the right order but gives me multiple rows for the same user, which is precisely the problem I'm trying to solve. So, what I *want is this exact result, but ONLY containing the very first item for any given user.

Comment: try adding `GROUP BY user.id`

Comment: You're right. I copied your original query and edited it, but didn't notice the missing `GROUP BY` from the SQL I copied. (From the `EDIT` portion of your question.) Fixed with my edit. If that doesn't fix it, you have issues with the data in your `JOIN`, like multiple rows in the `item` table, and you'll have to deal with them by using a sub-select on `MAX(timestamp)`. It's hard to say, though, because you only posted a single row of sample data from each table.

Comment: @Erty, umm... no offense, but that's precisely the nature of my question! I AM using group by in the exact context above and not getting the values I'm seeking.

Comment: @KenWhite, I'm not sure what values you're using to test, but when I do this exact same thing, what I notice is that the order of the RESULTING (joined) rows do in fact come back based on the item.timestamp. However, the timestamp itself is still the one from the lowest IDd item.  See what I mean?  The DESC seems to be working on the resulting table *after the group_by, which knocks all the values from the original item table out and leaves just the lowest one behind.

Comment: Post some sample data from each table (in your original question), so we have data to work with trying to help you. This "conversation" trying to guess what you might be asking is silly. :-) I suspect what you're wanting to do involves a sub-select for the items table and then joining to that, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a `JOIN`. First create a subselect grouping by user and selecting the `MAX` of timestamp. This gets you one row per user, with the latest entry (and loses all other fields).

Then join it back using the timestamp in the `JOIN` expression, to restore the missing fields.

Sorry, but without the table schema it isn't easy to be more specific than this. Hope that the `JOIN` reference points you in the right direction to modify your query.